# Mahalanobis distance in $\mathbb R^3$ or more dimension

Tags: statistics, multilinear-algebra

Does anyone know how Mahalanobis distance looks like in $\mathbb R^3$ or $n$ dimensions. I would also be grateful if someone could give a geometrical interpretation in $\mathbb R^3$? Thank you a lot.

Comment: This notion of distance (or at least the name for it) is uncommon enough that I don't think I've heard of it. It might help encourage more/better answers if you include a definition in your question.

Comment: [***Wikipedia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) has a pretty lucid explanation of Mahalanobis_distance.